Restore shuffled function output
There is a function $\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x})$ that takes a vector $\mathbf{x}$ as input and outputs another vector $\mathbf{y}$. The function $f(\mathbf{x})$ is continuous and differentiable. I can query the function by a vector $\mathbf{x}$ and receive a  perturbed output as follows: $\tilde{\mathbf{y}} = \pi \cdot \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{e}$, where $\pi$ is a permuted identical matrix that shuffles the elements of $\mathbf{y}$, and $\mathbf{e}$ is a small uniform noise vector for further perturbation (since the shuffling does not change the values). The $\pi$ and $\mathbf{e}$ are differently for each input.
Given an oracle input-output pair $(\mathbf{x}_a, \mathbf{y}_a)$ and another pair $(\mathbf{x}_b, \tilde{\mathbf{y}}_b)$ with a perturbed output, I want to restore the order of $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}_b$, i.e., minimize the error $\mathbf{e}^{\prime} = \text{rec}(\tilde{\mathbf{y}}_b) - \mathbf{y}_b$, where $\text{rec}(\cdot)$ represents some efforts to align the vectors. Note that the function $f(\cdot)$, permutation matrices, and noise vectors are all unknown to me. Adding noise can mix the data so that recover the order is harder. The larger the noise vector $\mathbf{e}$, the harder it is to restore the original order. Therefore, I want to estimate the ratio $\frac{\|\mathbf{e}^{\prime}\|}{\|\mathbf{e}\|}$. I understand that this seems like a hard problem, so there may be some relaxation to compute its lower bound.
As a possible way to align the output and understand the problem, we can construct a sequence ${(\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0}), (\mathbf{x}_{1}, \tilde{\mathbf{y}}_{1}), \cdots (\mathbf{x}_{n}, \tilde{\mathbf{y}}_{n})}$, where $\mathbf{x}_{0} = \mathbf{x}_a$, $\mathbf{x}_{n} = \mathbf{x}_b$, and $\mathbf{x}_{i+1} - \mathbf{x}_{i} = \frac{\mathbf{x}_b - \mathbf{x}_a}{n}$. If $n$ is large enough, any two adjacent pairs have very close input and output, so the output is possible to align according to the values. Then, the first and last pairs can be aligned.
I also notice that some factors may affect the ratio $\frac{\|\mathbf{e}^{\prime}\|}{\|\mathbf{e}\|}$. For example, a large length or small output range of the output vector $\mathbf{y}$ makes the alignment harder, as the data are densely concentrated. This could be as factors appeared in the ratio.

What is a "permuted identical matrix"? Do you mean a permutation matrix (every entry is $0$ or $1$, and every row and column contains a single $1$ in it)? Or do you mean something else? And am I correct that by calling $\bf e$ "noise", you mean that for each evaluation of $\mathbf y = f(\mathbf x)$, the value of $\bf e$ may be different? Or is it a fixed vector whose value is unknown other than some estimate of its size?

Yes, it means the permutation matrix you mentioned. The value of $\mathbf{e}$ is different for each input but the sampling range is known.

If you can choose a $\bf x$, then if you choose the component elements $x_i$ are separated from each other by more than twice the upper limit on $\bf e$, then for each $x_i$, there would be only one $y_j$ that could be its image, which would allow you to determine the permutation exactly.

The mapping between elements in $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is not a one-to-one mapping. Therefore, I believe that the distance between inputs cannot guarantee the separation of outputs. Additionally, since the function is a non-linear mapping, it also fails to preserve such a correspondence.

I'm a bit unclear on your question. Do you mean $\mathbf{y}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}$ have a one-to-one mapping without the contribution of $\mathbf{e}$? Regardless, my primary interest lies in the range of $\mathbf{e}$ can cause overlapping of elements.

Some of what I said in that comment confused what is actually needed for the method I gave earlier with the concept of the "function" $f(\mathbf x) = \pi\mathbf x + \mathbf e$ being one-to-one (which it only fails to be for the same reason it fails to be a function: $\bf e$ is not the same for each evaluation). For this reason, I have deleted it. I gave a comment above instead of an answer because I wasn't sure that your situation could me the requirements I gave. I am still not sure, but am answering below to more fully explain what I meant.

If you are able to freely select an input vector $\bf x$, and it is known that

$\pi$ is a permutation matrix, and
There is a value $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $i$, $|e_i| < \epsilon$ (for example, knowing $\|\mathbf e\| < \epsilon$ would be sufficient),

then you can determine $\pi$ completely from a single input. Simply choose the elements of $\bf x$ to be distinct, and separated from each other by at least $2\epsilon$.
Let $\bf z = \pi x$. Thus $\bf y = z + e$. We do not know what $\bf z$ is, but because its elements are just those of $\bf x$ rearranged, we know what those elements are, just not what order they are in. But because the elements of $\bf y$ differ from those of $\bf z$ by less than $\epsilon$, and the elements of $\bf z$ differ from each other by more than $2\epsilon$, for each element of $\bf y$, there is only one element of $\bf z$ that corresponds. So this tells us the order of $\bf z$, which, because they are distinct, tells us the permutation $\pi$ that they underwent.
For example, suppose we have the simple case of 3-dimensional vectors, and we can take $\epsilon = 1$. Then we can choose $$\bf x = \begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\4\end{bmatrix}.$$ For $\bf y$, we might get
$$\bf y = \begin{bmatrix}2.9\\-0.3\\3.2\end{bmatrix}$$
Since each element of $\bf y$ has to be within $1$ of some element of $\bf x$, we get that $2.9$ must have come from $2, -0.3$ must have come from $0, 3.2$ must have come from $4$. Thus it must be that
$$\bf z = \begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}$$
and so $\pi = [213] = (12)(3)$ or the matrix
$$\pi = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you for your response, which provides a key insight into how to mitigate the effect of shuffling. However, I believe your answer simplifies the question by assuming that $f(\mathbf{x})$ is an identity function. In your explanation, you state "but because its elements are just those of $\mathbf{x}$ rearranged". This should be $f(\mathbf{x})$ rearranged. I suspect this misunderstanding may have arisen because I did not explicitly mention that $f(\mathbf{x})$ is unknown for someone attempting to restore the original order after shuffling. I will update the question to clarify this point.

I thought $f$ was the permutation matrix plus the noise, not a separate function applied before the permutation matrix. But this was my mistake. I had misread it. I'll leave the post up for now as a possible concept, But it fails to offer a solution.

There is no way to separate the actions of $\pi$ from that of $f$. To see this, suppose $\sigma$ is another permutation, but fixed. And consider $g(\mathbf x) = \sigma(f(\mathbf x))$. The results you would get from running any tests on $g$ would be indentical in nature to those obtained from $f$. In fact, they would be results from $f$, but with the random permutation being $\pi\circ \sigma$ instead of $\pi$ alone. There is no way you can ever distinguish between $f$ and $g$ with these tests.

Yes, you are right. I believe this is another insight you provide :). The shuffling scheme can always be absorded by the $f(\cdot)$ to become another shuffling scheme. Therefore, I use the orcal pair $(\mathbf{x}_a, \mathbf{y}_a)$ as the starting point, which fix the function behavior without any randomness.

Yes - depending on your ultimate goal that uncertainty could be a show-stopper, or it could be a simplification of the problem. If you goal was to find the specific $f$, then there is no way to do it. But if your goal is to find some $f$ that provides the output you see, then it almost completely solves the issue of $\pi$ - just choose a convenient ordering. For example, you could choose $f$ to always have its elements in increasing order. Then simply sorting the output adjusts for $\pi$ - except for the influence of $\bf e$.

In order to handle $\bf e$, you have to also know something about $f$. For example, is it continuous? Or better, smooth? If $f$ is not continuous, then knowing the values of $\bf y$ for particular points $\bf x$ tells nothing about the values of $\bf y$ for even nearby $\bf x$. There would be nothing you could do. So you want $f$ to be at least continuous. and preferably analytic (estimatible by polynomials). Then you can least-squares or other methods to best fit an estimated function to your data.

You may regard the $f(\cdot)$ as polynomials. This will be updated to the question.
